# How to filter records in datagrid view and show the selected record in the datagrid

Tags: vb.net

Please I have a datagridview with transaction bindingsource I want the datagrid to show the sorted rows only not all the records when i enter a value into a textbox and click button sort. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put code like this in your control :

```
 YourGridViewBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("YourDBColumn Like ;'*" & FilterValue) & "*'"
```

for example you can use the code as your `TextBox.textchanged` control to filter the Datagrid view as you type in the TextBox