# How can I filter the result of sql select query on datagrid view

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, filter

I have a Sql query on my form displaying all records having a duedate of the year 2013 in my tableA filling the datagrid view. And I have also a button and textbox.

What I wanted to do is to filter the result of my sql query on the datagrid view, Is it Possible to have another sql like this:

`"SELECT caseno, duedate,remarks from (the data on my datagrid view)"`

this is my datagrid sample:

```
    caseno      duedate       remarks
    1001        1/12/13       passed
    1002        1/22/13       passed
    1003        1/15/13       failed
    1004        1/20/13       none
    1005        1/06/13       failed
```

when I click the button I want to display on my datagrid all the records having a remarks that i typed on my textbox. anyone can help me? tnx! try to make it simple :)

Comment: can you share your codes on how did you bind your data to `DataGridView`?

Comment: I did not code it, I just select the binding source in datagrid properties

Comment: you're using `dataSet`, `dataTable`, `tableAdapter`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

1. Set datasource of datagridview to select sql query
2. Bind data only when text change event occurs
3. Do a validation on the textbox text on button click event

Reference: [How to filter records in datagrid view and show the selected record in the datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786556/how-to-filter-records-in-datagrid-view-and-show-the-selected-record-in-the-datag)

Solution 2:

Check on this post on [codeproject for Filter DataGridview with data entered in textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/431281/Filter-DataGridView-with-the-text-entered-in-TextB)

The important point to notice that you can use `DataView`'s `.RowFilter` with the parameter you enter in the `textbox`. Then bind that DataView to the `RowSource` of `GridView`. In the above sample it's using:

```
dataview.RowFilter = "Year(Duedate) = " + textBox1.Text + ";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataview;
```

You may also find lots of other articles as well here in SO.

Comment: there is no dataview.rowfilter in vb.net

Comment: Then you can follow with the first solution.

Comment: i already have select query that is displaying all the records having a duedate this year at the event of form_load. what I want is to filter the records in datagridview depending on the remarks i'll type to textbox

Answer (score 0):

your select statement for filtering remarks:

```
SELECT caseno, duedate, remarks FROM yourTable name where remarks = '"& txt1.text &"'
```

you can also make a combobox that consist of list of remarks and replace txt1.text to combobox1.text

to put it on a datagridview: (in your button event)

```
    'declare your dataset and adapter
    Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

Try

        connect()
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT caseno, duedate, remarks FROM yourTable name where remarks = '"& txt1.text &"'", con)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        yourdatagridview.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

 Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [BindingSource.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
 BindingSource.Filter = "caseno Like '" textBox.Text + "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

by using dataview row filter you can filter the data